# Flush confusion

Tags: flush

Player 1 : 6♣ 3♠
Money put : $75k
Player 2 : T♠ K♠
Money put : $75k (all-in)
Table :  2♣ 3♣ 5♣ T♣ Q♣
Pot : $210k

The flush is on the table.

Who should get the money? Who wins ? What's the share exactly? Should both players split equally?

Answer (score 1):

Player 1 wins this pot because player 1 has the best 5 card hand.

player 1 best 5 card hand: 3 5 6 T Q (all clubs)

player 2 best 5 card hand: 2 3 5 T Q (all clubs)

Comment: You have VTC privilege

Comment: It's not clubs, the player 2 has...

Comment: thought it was worth answering to address OP's specific situation. I will mark it next time @paparazzo